# Topological counterexample: compact, Hausdorff, separable space which is not first-countable

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, separable-spaces, first-countable

I need an example for a compact, Hausdorff, separable space which is not first-countable.
I tried to look for it for some time without success...

Comment: Check [this site](http://www.austinmohr.com/spacebook) out.

Comment: $\beta \omega$ satisfies the first three properties clearly. It takes a little work to show it is not first countable though.

Comment: @David Mitra: This is a fantastic site. You should write this as an answer so that more people know about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The space $I^I$ (i.e., product of $\mathfrak c$-many copies of the unit interval $I=[0,1]$ is a compact Hausdorff space.

It is not first-countable, see here: [Uncountable Cartesian product of closed interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67553/uncountable-cartesian-product-of-closed-interval)

It is separable by Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery theorem,
see here: [On the product of $\mathfrak c$-many separable spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97413/on-the-product-of-separable-spaces)

As pointed out in a comment, we could also prove separability by directly showing that polynomials with rational coefficients form a countable dense subset. See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97413/on-the-product-of-mathfrak-c-many-separable-spaces/97425#97425) for a similar approach in a slightly different space.

Comment: No big theorem is needed to show this space is separable. For example, polyomial functions with rational coefficients do the job. Given $\epsilon > 0$ and finitely many points $a_i,b_i$ in $I$, there exists a rational polynomial $p$ with $p(a_i) \approx_\epsilon b_i$.